# Values from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, class, outer-join

I need to get `Strings` from one class `LocationGetter.java`:

```
      @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int latitute = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int longitude = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    String lat = (String.valueOf(latitute));
    String lon = (String.valueOf(longitude));

    //latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    //longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
  }
```

to another class `ParseJSON.java`:

```
public String readWeatherFeed() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=46d1ef574c094426121012&format=json&q="+lat+","+lon);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();

}
```

So I want to use the values String lat, lon from the first class in the URL-string of the second class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

;) you need use intent and BroadcastReceiver  to know that the download completed and use AsyncTask that the download JSON

you have many work

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `String lat, lon` from LocationGetter class to ParseJSON class by creating an Object of `ParseJSON` class in LocationGetter class as:

```
     @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int latitute = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int longitude = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    String lat = (String.valueOf(latitute));
    String lon = (String.valueOf(longitude));
    ParseJSON parsjosnobj=new ParseJSON();
    String strresutn =parsjosnobj.readWeatherFeed(lat,lon)
    //latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    //longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
  }
```

and in `ParseJSON` class make your `readWeatherFeed` parametrized as :

```
public String readWeatherFeed(String lat,String lon) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://free.worldweatheronline.com
   /feed/weather.ashx?key=46d1ef574c094426121012&format=json&q="+lat+","+lon);
    try {
   //your code here
```

**NOTE :** this solution only work when your `ParseJSON` class is not an Activity .if `ParseJSON` is an Activity then use Intent to Pass data from One Activity to Other

Answer (score 0):

If these are across multiple activities, you can pass them via intent extras. In your first class, when you define the Intent to launch the second Activity, you add an extra.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", mLatitude);
intent.putExtra("lon", mLongitude);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the second activity, you can get those out via getExtras.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
float latitude = extras.getFloat("lat");
float longitude = extras.getFloat("lon");
```